# #include – build fails after switching from <> to ""

Tags: c, linux, gcc, include, gentoo

A commit in the C implementation of the Nokogumbo gem is causing the build to fail on Gentoo Linux, however, the modification is minor and shouldn't cause any trouble. Unfortunately, I know next to zilch about C.

Here's the commit:

https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo/commit/8b4446847dea5c614759684ebcae4c580c47f4ad

It simply replaces the `<>` with `""`:

```
-#include <gumbo.h>
-#include <error.h>
-#include <parser.h>
+#include "gumbo.h"
+#include "error.h"
+#include "parser.h"
```

According to the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html) this shouldn't cause any trouble since it falls back to the previous behaviour:

> `#include "file"`
>
> This variant is used for header files of your own program. It searches for a file named file first in the directory containing the current file, then in the quote directories and then the same directories used for `<file>`. You can prepend directories to the list of quote directories with the -iquote option.

Unfortunately, while it compiles just fine with `<>`, the build fails with `""`:

```
compiling nokogumbo.c
nokogumbo.c:24:20: fatal error: parser.h: No such file or directory
#include "parser.h"
```

I'm wondering to what degree the way `<>` and `""` behaves depends on the toolchain, environment and other settings.

Thanks a lot for your hints!

Comment: This is non-compliant behavior. If an include with `" "` fails, the compiler must try again as if you had written `< >`. So something is terribly wrong with your gcc.

Comment: How do you call gcc, from an IDE or through command line? In case of IDE:s, there might be some IDE hiccup where it manually creates an include path with `-I` and only passes that to gcc. "Vanilla gcc" from command line shouldn't have these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing "gumbo" on the Gentoo box has fixed the problem. Apparently, a local installation mess has produced this weird behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

I checked your git repository and I noticed that you compile code with `--std=c99`. I think this may cause the problem, Because I found this in `C99` draft:

> The named  source  file  is  searched for in an implementation-defined
>   manner .If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the
>   directive is reprocessed as if it read

```
#include <header>
```

So it means process is first implementation defined, and **if not supported** it uses `#include<>` mode. But this means if it defines that `#include""` searches current directory, it will stop searching like `#include<>`.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the standard. "or if the search fails" is very clear, the compiler must try again as if you had written `< >`. This is not unique to C99 either, it has always been like that.